# Bathroom Exhaust - Idea

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-vent, exhaust

I am doing a major remodel of my primary bathroom.  Instead of the traditional exhaust fans I am thinking of doing something like:

1. Run 3x14" duct in the wall stud cavity from the bathroom ceiling to the basment
2. Do that both in the toilet room and just outside the shower
3. In the basement tie both to 6" dia duct that has an inline fan and damper and out the basement wall
4. In the wall, as close to ceiling as the trim will allow, have a 12"x1" vent opening

The house is on a pretty big hill, so the basement is walk out.  No problem getting the vent to the outside.  The basement is unfinished with 10' floor to deck to so no access problems.

Anyone see a problem with this plan?

Full disclosure - I saw something like this on YouTube, but it was pretty light on details.

Comment: It should work if the fan is powerful enough.  Short and straight is recommended for most vents.  Is there a problem of just popping it right though the wall to outside?

Comment: I like the idea of having the fan (and the noise) in the basement plus the clean look of all recessed lighting in the ceiling.

Comment: Putting the fan in the ceiling means having to open up more ceiling (not a huge deal) and getting on a really tall ladder to core those wall holes

Comment: Switching may be a hassle.

Comment: Can you expand on "Switching may be a hassle."  My thought is one switch in the bathroom to the fan in the basement.  When it's on, I am venting both openings.  Not the most efficient, but simpler is better.

Comment: Usually if an inline fan serves multiple rooms it runs at a relatively low speed 24/7.  Though you can make it 18/7 or whatever.  It can't provide a high flow boost to one room to handle steam or smells. Your idea is fine but not ideal for the situation.    Also, if the toilet room is within the bathroom, and you put an intake there, you don't need another one just outside the shower. Air will flow in the main door, into the toilet and out your exhaust serving both rooms.  Think FLOW.

Comment: I like your idea and thinking outside of the box.  My concerns would be the humid air from when the shower is used condensing inside the walls.  Thinking that the usual 4 inch bath vent moves air through aprox. 12.5 sq inch area, your 12 x 1 slot would be close.  The 6 inch vent out of the basement is much larger and should move the air, just slower.  I'm wondering if the slow movement will be an issue, and/or will the air flow at the 12" slot be drawn faster and that will make a noise that is undesirable.    If you do this please report back and let us all know the results.  Good Luck.

Comment: This has the makings of a good question but I have downvoted it because you skipped some important information: What are you trying to achieve?  Why be untraditional?  Does the bathroom itself have no outside walls?  Are you trying to avoid noise in the bathroom (but not in the basement)?  Is there no unfinished space above the bathroom?  Also, a shower vent duct should be insulated.  3x14 duct implies you're using an entire stud bay with no scope for insulation.  More info please!